# Differentiable manifold test

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was wondering how to test that the equations $x=2z^{4}+6$ and $y=z^{2}+1$ define a $C^{\infty}$ differentiable manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with dimension $1$. Edit: I'm very familiar with the implicit function theorem, and I know that it has to be done using that, but I don't know how to relate it with a differentiable manifold.

Comment: Your equations define a smooth curve on $\mathbb R^3$ without intersections. Hence it is a smooth manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition (in this case): let be $g:{\Bbb R}^3\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^2$. $g(x,y,z) = 0$ defines a submanifold if $Dg$ has maximal rank (2 in this case). See http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap6.pdf.

Alternatively: (as suggested by Dog_69): the parametrization
$$x = 2z^4 + 6,$$
$$y = z^2 + 1,$$
$$z = z,$$
has rank 1.